# Checkout: shopping cart price rule is only applied after pressing the 'update cart' button

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm running Magento 1.9.2.2. and I've added a shopping cart price rule:

If the customer buys more than one t-shirt, he should get a discount of 10$ per t-shirt. The t-shirt is a configurable product (the linked simple products are f.e. green t-shirt in S, red t-shirt XL,...). Now the customer can either get 2 red t-shirts in S (1 item, quantity 2) or 1 red shirt in S and 1 black t-shirt in XL (2 items, each quantity 1). He should get the discount of 10$ per t-shirt in both cases.

I didn't find a way to check if the customer has 2 or more of those skus in his shopping cart, but I found a way to cheat: As I don't use the weight attribute at all, I gave all those t-shirt products a weight of 1 and checked that in the conditions tab of the price rule:

```
 If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:

      Total Weight equals or greater than 2
```

This way I can find out if the customer has more than 2 t-shirts in his shopping cart. Now in the Actions tab of the price rule I apply the rule to the t-shirts:

```
 If ANY of these conditions are TRUE:

      SKU is one of t-shirt-green-S,t-shirt-green-M,t-shirt-green-L,...
```

Lo and behold, the customer gets a fixed amount discount of 10 per t-shirt, if he has more than 2 in his shopping cart, which is working fine...

...but when I open the shopping cart page the rule is not applied immediately. I have to press either the 'update cart' button or change the quantity of an item and press 'update'  - then the discount is shown and applied.

If I create a simple price rule (f.e. 10 $ discount for any item) and go to the shopping cart page, the discount is shown immediately, no need to update the cart.

I know that I probably defeated myself somehow, but I have no idea how :) - so how do I get rid of that 'update cart' problem? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could put

```php
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->updateItems()->save();
```

into `protected function _getCartProductIds()` from

`public/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php`

for example.

---

Don't forget to copy the file into:

`public/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php`

before you make the changes.